# Accessing OSGi bundle's interface from an EJB

Tags: eclipse, jboss, ejb, osgi, ear

I have a very basic knowledge of OSGi and I would like to ask the following questions:

Is it possible to call a service or interface of OSGi from an EJB in the JBoss 7.1 server running?

If yes, let's say I have an EJB that implements "HelloWorld" from a bundle. What exactly happens in the runtime if I stop this bundle and start another one?

I would really appreciate if anyone can provide an example how to do manage this.

Thank you!

Comment: I would try to separate both worlds from each other, cause   
a) you bind yourself to JBoss 7.1 (Wildfly doesn't support OSGi anymore)  
b) you mix up two different technologies with different views for class-loading   

Instead try to have some sort of other "communication" between your EJB and the OSGi world.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Do you have any example that helps to create a bridge between them?

Comment: Broker like architecture (JMS), use WebSerivces anything besides RMI ;)